# How to apply a rule to the home page in plone.app.theming diazo rules.xml

Tags: plone, xdv, diazo

I'm trying to create a specific rule for the home page of a site. At the moment I use this rule:

```xslt
   <before css:theme="#mppeditbar" content="/html/body/*" if-path="/Plone/" href="slideshow/index.htm"/>
```

It works for localhost, but not with a proxy path in front of Plone.

How could I apply this rule to home page of my site ?

Comment: Is this really a "rules" question? I'd expect some other factor to be involved for why it works on localhost and not the proxy host. But I'm not sure.

Comment: as laurence said in its answer it might be considered as a bug. the if-path='/' may work on http://localhost:8080/Plone/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm presuming you're using virtual hosting with the proxy. That will change the path from /Plone/ to /. You can include multiple whitespace separated paths in if-path, but with Plone testing the body class is normally the easiest way to do it.

On second thoughts, I might consider this a bug. With plone.app.theming, includes are rooted at the site root, so I guess if-path="/" should probably match localhost:8080/Plone.

Comment: Hmm. On second thoughts, I might consider this a bug. With plone.app.theming, includes are rooted at the site root, so I guess if-path="/" should probably match http://localhost:8080/Plone.

Comment: I would say a feature. theming can depends on related path (/intranet, /blog, /, ...) making it working for localhost should be nice !

Answer (score 3):

Something like `css:if-content="body.section-front-page"` should do the trick. If you base your rule conditions on the actual content, you can even check for single elements like e.g. `css:if-content="#frontpage-scrollable` for switching to a dedicated front page theme template.

Comment: This tips work only if you don't change the default page and you never change the view.